# CSS - border-bottom double 1 thick 1 thin

Tags: css, border

Is it possible with a single CSS?

Having a double border, the inner border is thin while the outer border is thick?

Having two different element with different border thickness is simple.
But I'm trying to find a way to make it a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below??

You can use **outline**

Outlines allow both a border and an outline to be applied to a single element.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0er2u066/13/)**

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.border {
    border: 1px double #000;
    outline: 5px solid #699;
    outline-offset: -9px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I will not vote down because this what I posted as answer (and deleted) but still you can find the same answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181183/css-double-border-with-outer-border-thicker-than-inner-border

Comment: Oops, I forgot to specify that I only need to do it for the bottom-border. The outline gives border to all sides.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/4qvLx2tr/

Comment: @mary Question title specifies it. I guess there's no need? :)

Comment: @Richa gave the best answer.  There is more info here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/, though they are not restricting it to just the bottom border.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use any other CSS property then you can use the following code.

```
border: double 3px black;
outline: solid 1px black;
```

It will produce a 1px inner and 2px outer "border"